# VBA error in data validation - Run time error '1004': Application defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The purpose of this code is meant to format a range of cells and then program a data validation list into one of the cells. However, when I try this code, it continues to throw the error listed above upon reaching the line of code where I have Validation.Add .Can someone help me with this issue and maybe explain why this error is being triggered.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim defaultRow As Range
    Dim currentCellNum As Integer
    Set defaultRow = ActiveSheet.Range("R1:X1")
    currentCellNum = 1
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Activate
        .Range("A" & currentCellNum).Select
        .Range("A" & currentCellNum) = defaultRow

        .Range("A" & currentCellNum).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        .Range("B" & currentCellNum).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        .Range("C" & currentCellNum).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        .Range("D" & currentCellNum).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        .Range("E" & currentCellNum).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        .Range("F" & currentCellNum).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        .Range("G" & currentCellNum).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        
        .Range("A" & currentCellNum).Select
        .Range("A" & currentCellNum).Validation.Delete
        .Range("A" & currentCellNum).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertsStop, Formula1:="A,B,C,D"

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `xlValidAlertStop` instead of Alert{S}

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()
    Dim defaultRow As Range
    Dim currentCellNum As Integer
    Set defaultRow = ActiveSheet.Range("R1:X1")
    currentCellNum = 1
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Activate
        .Range("A" & currentCellNum).Select
        .Range("A" & currentCellNum) = defaultRow

        .Range("A" & currentCellNum).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        .Range("B" & currentCellNum).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        .Range("C" & currentCellNum).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        .Range("D" & currentCellNum).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        .Range("E" & currentCellNum).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        .Range("F" & currentCellNum).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        .Range("G" & currentCellNum).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        
        With .Range("A" & currentCellNum).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="A,B,C,D"  '"=$E$5:$E$15"
        End With
        
    End With
End Sub
```